# Migrating from Joda time to Java 8 DateTime

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, jodatime

I could not find an alternative `toDateTimeAtStartOfTheDay`. For example
`DateTime.now().toLocalDate().toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().plusHours(10)`

how would I write above code in Java 8's DateTime library?
Closest I came to `ZonedDateTime.now().toLocalDate().atStartOfDay()` which just prints `2015-07-21T00:00`.

 I want something like `2015-07-21T00:00:00.000-04:00`

Comment: Do you just need that string?

Comment: Yes. Time in that format.

Comment: Then try `ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T10:00:00.000'Z")` and don't bother calculating 10 o'clock manually if you just can use a fixed pattern for that.

Comment: Thanks. It almost worked.  Just that UTC difference coming up as `-400` not `-4:00`.

Comment: Got it, It will be `"yyyy-MM-dd'T10:00:00.00‌​0'XXX"`

Comment: Oh, you too found that? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the time as a formatted String and you always like to get 10 o'clock of today, then don't bother calculating that time manually and write it into a format pattern:

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T10:00:00.000'XXX");
```

The meaning of each letter can be found here: [JavaDoc of `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). `'T10:00:00.000'` is a fixed string and won't be parsed, just "added" to the returned String.

You can get the formatted time like this:

```
 ZonedDateTime.now().format(format);
```

The output would be:

> 2015-07-21T10:00:00.000-04:00

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
 LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```